# undetermined coefficients in DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

given y"+4y'=16x find a general solution through undetermined coefficients. I have found yc to be

yc = c1 + c2e^(-x)

and I have chosen yp to be

yp = ax^2 + bx

Just wondering if this yp is a good choice

Comment: Plug it in and check.

Comment: @javahelp: Your $x_p = ax^2 + b x $ is absolutely correct.Your $y_c$ has an error in exponent, it should be  $e^{-4x}$.

Comment: okay so then 2A + 8ax + 4b = 16x   so a=2 and there is b = 0 since there is no answer with no x value

Comment: Nope..........., they should be $-1, 2$. Please resolve.

Comment: how could it be -1, 2? i got yp = ax^2 +bx then y'p+ 2ax + b then y''p+ 2a

Comment: oh i see it should be 4+4b = 0 so then b = -1

Comment: @Moo does that look correct to you?

Comment: After substituting, you have $8 a x + (2a + 4 b ) = 16 x$. From this, you have $8 a = 16 \implies a = 2$ and $2a + 4b = 4 + 4 b = 0 \implies b = -1$

Comment: perfect thats what i got too, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your complementary functions contains a constant $c_1$, so you are correct in multiply the "usual/default" particular integral $y_{p_o} = ax + b$ by $x$ to get $y_p = ax^2 + bx$.